# assembly x86 code and process virtual memory

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

i am trying to understand piece of code below

```
data dd 1,2,3,4,5,6
myfunc:
lea eax, data
cmp eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
jle SHORT L1
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
add  ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] 
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], ecx 
mov edx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] 
sub edx, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], edx
 mov  eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
 sub eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
 mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], eax
 L1:
 mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
```

first line i understand it will be loaded in the process virtual memory as `dd` is defined with `4 bytes` so something like this perhaps?

```
data dd 1,2,3,4,5,6

4004000  01 ; 1
4004001  00 ; 0
4004002  00 ; 0
4004003  00 ; 0

4004004  02 ; 2
4004005  00 ; 0
4004006  00 ; 0
4004007  00 ; 0

4004008  03 ; 3
4004009  00 ; 0
400400A  00 ; 0
400400B  00 ; 0

4004008  04 ; 4
4004009  00 ; 0
400400A  00 ; 0
400400B  00 ; 0

400400C  05 ; 5
400400D  00 ; 0
400400E  00 ; 0
400400F  00 ; 0

4004010  06 ; 6
4004011  00 ; 0
4004012  00 ; 0
4004013  00 ; 0
```

however, the after the label it will load memory address of var `data` into `eax` register then compares value of eax with DWORD present at [ebp-8]

what i don't understand is there is no address in ebp as i assume so may be its missing `mov ebp,esp` ?

also even if i move esp into ebp what i don't understand the part is the code says `ebp-8` which should be `ebp-4` perhaps to point to the address of first DWORD defined ?

can someone please guide me to the right direction ?

thanks!

Comment: yeah, that's weird to use `[ebp-8]` without using `push ebp` / `mov ebp,esp` at the top of the function.  But that would be a local, not a function arg, (because it's below EBP), so it just plain doesn't make sense for this to be a stand-alone function.  It's probably a block that an existing function can jump to.  And BTW, `lea eax, data` is just silly; `mov eax, OFFSET data` is shorter and faster, and has no disadvantage.  `cmp eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]` seems to be comparing a static address (in `eax`) with a local variable.  The code looks pretty crap; is it compiler-generated debug mode?

Comment: Hey Peter, yeah true it looks pretty crap, its a block provided to me for research purposes probably from IDA Pro from a disassembled PE to understand what this function is doing along with effect of instructions on cpu registers. so if i do `push ebp` and `mov ebp,esp` outside the function `myfunc` i would have the starting address in ebp, however when it is tries to compare with `eax` wouldn't it be `invalid` address because ebp-4 does not exists? i am trying to understand what does these instructions do when executed

Comment: Of course `ebp-4` would exist.  It would even be mapped into your process's address space.  It would be below `esp` and thus subject to being clobbered asynchronously, unless your function also did `sub esp, 12`.  A normal function *would* do that to reserve space for locals.

Comment: It's very clear this is not the start of a function, or it's a private helper function that uses the parent function's stack frame.  The label isn't really `myfunc` is it?  Are you just guessing that it's the start of a function and not a block within a function?

Comment: Thanks @Peter Cordes, unfortunately i am still not able to figure out what will be the content of the registers once this subtract and addition happens to the `ebp` register. i don't have more information wether its a block within a function, its just an excerpt what i have.

Comment: Ok, well it's obviously a block of a function, not a whole function.  `[ebp-4]` and `[ebp-8]` are local variables that are already set to something.  Apparently it makes sense to add them together, because that's what happens if the first branch is not-taken.

Comment: @PeterCordes what i could understand is it loads `data dd` into virtual memory then if we move `esp` to `ebp` and then we compare and subtract value of `ebp-8` but i couldn't visualise what would be present at `ebp-8` and what it will compare with

Comment: No, it's comparing with the value in memory at `[ebp-8]`, not with `ebp-8` stack address.  The local variables are already initialized to something when this block runs, so it would take more than just creating a stack frame; some code that sets these locals to something must come first.  Also, `data dd ...` is already in virtual memory when the process executes.  The assembler / linker places the data there in the executable, next to the code.  Nothing loads the data though, only setting `eax` from the address of `data`.

Comment: Thanks alot @PeterCordes finally understood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... its a block provided to me for research purposes probably from IDA Pro from a disassembled PE to understand what this function is doing along with effect of instructions on cpu registers
>
> ... i am trying to understand what does these instructions do when executed
>
> ... unfortunately i am still not able to figure out what will be the content of the registers once this subtract and addition happens to the `ebp` register

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
add  ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] 
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], ecx 
mov edx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] 
sub edx, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], edx
mov  eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
sub eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], eax
```

This code in essence just switches the local variables at `[ebp-8]` and `[ebp-4]`.
In stead of requiring 9 instructions and clobbering 3 registers, it could have been written like:

```
    mov edx, [ebp-8]
    mov eax, [ebp-4] 
    mov [ebp-4], edx
    mov [ebp-8], eax
```

---

```
lea eax, data
cmp eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
jle SHORT L1
...
L1:
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
```

Re-writing the test for clarity:

```
    cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-8], data
    jge SHORT L1
    ...
L1:
    mov eax, [ebp-8]
```

If the local variable at `[ebp-8]` is greater or equal than the startaddress of the array, it becomes the result in `EAX`.

If the local variable at `[ebp-8]` is less than the startaddress of the array, the original contents of `[ebp-4]` become the result in `EAX`.

---

If the switching part were of no importance, next code would produce the same `EAX`:

```
    mov eax, [ebp-8]
    cmp eax, data
    jge SHORT L1
    mov eax, [ebp-4]
L1:
```